# Loading html into chrome followed by jsdom instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer, jsdom

I'm doing some scraping after receiving html from an api. I'd like to do the following:

1. Open html page in chrome so I can find selectors in the console.
2. Immediately load the same html page into a jsdom instance
3. Drop into the repl - I can then find the right selectors in the console and test them out in a live jsdom environment to see if they work.

For 1, I have:

```
async function openHtml(htmlString) {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
 const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(htmlString);
return;
// await browser.close();
}
```

The code provided with the api is:

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);

    response = JSON.parse(body); //response.content = html, response.cookies = cookies

    const dom = new JSDOM(response.content);
    console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent); // "Hello world"

    openHtml(response.content);
    console.log('hi');
  });

});

req.end();
```

If I run the code at the command line the browser opens as expected. However, if I set a breakpoint at:

```
    console.log('hi');
```

It does not. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openHtml` is an async function. So you'll have to set the method calling in await (promise) and main function to async as well.

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = []
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk)
    })

    res.on('end', async function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks)

        response = JSON.parse(body) //response.content = html, response.cookies = cookies

        const dom = new JSDOM(response.content)
        console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector('p').textContent) // 'Hello world'

        await openHtml(response.content)
        console.log('hi')
    })

})

req.end()
```